# How to formulate a SQL query with WHERE condition and more than x entries?

Tags: sql, vba, oracle

I automatically build a SQL query using a VBA macro after user input. The query looks something like this:

```sql
Select Distinct MATERIAL 
From MyTABLE 
Where (COND11) OR (COND12) OR COND13) OR (COND14) 
OR (COND21) OR (COND22) OR (COND23)
```

This yields me all materials that have the curvetype i. The conditions `CONDij` are conditions for the curvetype `i`. This works up to here. I have one curve type where sometimes only 1 point per condition is in the database. (In my case a youngs modulus vs temperature , if only room temperature is in the data base no curve can be plotted).

Now to the question. How would I formulate a query that yields all materials with at least two points per condition. A draft of it would maybe look like this:

```sql
Select Distinct MATERIAL 
From MyTABLE 
Where (COND11 AND (Select count(*) from MyTable Where COND11)>1) OR ... (same for other ij=
```

I don't get an error, it just "doesn't work" which means I still get curves with only 1 point.

EDIT: I have the suspiscion that the sub query: `Select count(*) from MyTable Where COND11)>1` is not restricted to the `Distinct Material` I am looking for. So the query searches for distinct materials but the subquery counts the amount of entries of any material that fullfill the conditions. **How would I restrict the material in the sub query?**

Here the full output of a query as an example. (I warn you it's a mess)

## Query

```sql
Select
  Distinct ArticleIDEMS,
  CompanyCDProd,
  ArticleShort
From
  V_Pruefungen
Where
  (
    (
      (
        PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
        AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
        AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '5'
        AND ZUSTAND = 'conditioned'
      )
      AND (
        Select
          Count(*)
        From
          V_Pruefungen
        Where
          (
            PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
            AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
            AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '5'
            AND ZUSTAND = 'conditioned'
          )
      ) > 2
    )
    OR (
      (
        PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
        AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
        AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '50'
        AND ZUSTAND = 'conditioned'
      )
      AND (
        Select
          Count(*)
        From
          V_Pruefungen
        Where
          (
            PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
            AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
            AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '50'
            AND ZUSTAND = 'conditioned'
          )
      ) > 2
    )
    OR (
      (
        PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
        AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
        AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '5'
        AND ZUSTAND = 'dry'
      )
      AND (
        Select
          Count(*)
        From
          V_Pruefungen
        Where
          (
            PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
            AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
            AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '5'
            AND ZUSTAND = 'dry'
          )
      ) > 2
    )
    OR (
      (
        PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
        AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
        AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '50'
        AND ZUSTAND = 'dry'
      )
      AND (
        Select
          Count(*)
        From
          V_Pruefungen
        Where
          (
            PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
            AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
            AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '50'
            AND ZUSTAND = 'dry'
          )
      ) > 2
    )
  )
```

EDIT:

## Example Result:

[image]

The materials that are listed here are the ones that **"have a curve"**. Having a curve means, that there are more than 2 data points that fullfill one of multiple of condition-sets. For example a tensile test can be done at 5 mm/min or at 50 mm/min with dry or conditioned sample state. That means there are 4 possible condition sets that allow a curve to be a tensile curve. Now if one of those condition sets has more than 2 points in them it is a curve. I know the curve conditions but I do not know how to restrict them to 2 points or more. This causes issues for the elastic modulus (E-Modulus) vs temperature curve. If a 23°C property exists in the database but nothing else no curve can be plotted. Since that is the case for some materials, they should be excluded in the query.

I hope that this elaboration has cleared the question a bit.

Comment: Could you post the full version of the current query?  Without seeing the tables to see why it's meeting another condition - it's just guesswork on this side.  Based on this it should work, albeit getting a count may not be necessary under the first condition.

Comment: @JimmySmith I can provide you with the full query which is a bloody mess, just to warn you. Just a tought now: Is it possible that the sub query doesn't restrict the material? I'll Reformulate some of the question.

Comment: It is, but I've seen much worse.  I wonder if you were to use a `HAVING` clause on the pieces where you currently have > 2 .  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Do these designations\BEZEICHNUNGs represent the room temperature?  Which piece is determining the only a room temperature.

Comment: You could use an `In` statement to clean up the cases a bit. E.g. `AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 IN('5','50')`. Could you do a count on your outside query then add a `having` clause as @JimmySmith pointed out?

Comment: It would be really helpful to see a sample data and expected result. I think the problem is that you have OR conditions so if one of those is true, you will get a result, even if there are less than 2 records for the other conditions.

Comment: What is the target RDBMS?

Comment: @ThomasG Oracle

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to recode your query in something more elegant, and with what you've shown, its hard to tell what would be the best performant solution.

Here's already a first attempt

```sql
SELECT V.ArticleIDEMS, V.CompanyCDProd, V.ArticleShort
FROM V_Pruefungen V
INNER JOIN
(
    Select
        ArticleIDEMS,
        SUM(CASE WHEN BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '5'  AND ZUSTAND = 'conditioned' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_cond_5, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '50' AND ZUSTAND = 'conditioned' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_cond_50,
        SUM(CASE WHEN BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '5'  AND ZUSTAND = 'dry' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_dry_5, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '50' AND ZUSTAND = 'dry' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_dry_50
    From
      V_Pruefungen
    WHERE
        PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
        AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'  
    GROUP BY ArticleIDEMS   
) C ON V.ArticleIDEMS=C.ArticleIDEMS     
WHERE C.cnt_cond_5 > 2
  AND C.cnt_cond_50 > 2
  AND C.cnt_dry_5 > 2
  AND C.cnt_dry_50 > 2
```

Try it and provide feedback

Note : I assumed  that `ArticleIDEMS` is a unique identifier for your articles records. If not the case, it probably wont work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time! Since I am restricted to use the `Where (Cond11 AND Cond21 ..) OR (Cond21 AND Cond22 ...) OR ...` construction I unfortunately cannot use your query. But you may have some inputs on the solution my colleague has proposed?

Answer (score 0):

This query was provided by a colleague of mine and it seems to work just fine, therefore problem solved.

```
select
  distinct articleidems,
  companycdprod,
  articleshort
from
  (
    select
      articleidems,
      companycdprod,
      articleshort,
      pruefbedingungen,
      einzelwert,
      bs_bezeichnung1
      zustand
    from
      v_pruefungen
    where(
        PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
        AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
        AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '5'
        AND ZUSTAND = 'conditioned'
      )
      OR (
        PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
        AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
        AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '50'
        AND ZUSTAND = 'conditioned'
      )
      OR (
        PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
        AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
        AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '5'
        AND ZUSTAND = 'dry'
      )
      OR (
        PRUEFBEDINGUNGEN = 'Tensile Test ISO 527'
        AND EINZELWERT = 'E-Modulus  [MPa]'
        AND BS_BEZEICHNUNG1 = '50'
        AND ZUSTAND = 'dry'
      )
    group by
      articleidems,
      companycdprod,
      articleshort,
      pruefbedingungen,
      einzelwert,
      bs_bezeichnung1
      zustand
    having
      count (*) > 1
  )
```